# Flutter Dart deserialize a json with dynamic key but structured values into Map<String, ModelClass>

Tags: json, flutter, dart, json-deserialization

Is it possible to deserialize a json with dynamic key but structured values into Map in flutter dart.

I am having a json like

```
{
   "data" : {
            "apple":{"qty":5, "price":100},
            "orange":{"qty":2, "price":40},
           }
}
```

And I want this to deserialize in **flutter/dart** to a model class below

```
class Data {
    Map<String, Item> itemMap;

    factory Data.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) {
        itemMap : json["data"]; //How to parse.
    }
}

class Item {
   int qty;
   int price;
}
```

I have read through a [medium blog](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51) and even this also not covering the Map part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to achieve it. We can convert the Map from one type to another.

```
class Data {
    Map<String, Item> itemMap;

    factory Data.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) {
        itemMap : getMapDataFrom(json["data"]); //How to parse.
    }

    static Map<String, Item> getFruitItemMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
       final Map<String, Item> fruitItemMap = HashMap();
       map.forEach((name, value) {
           bitItemLites[name] = Item.fromJson(value, name);
       });

       return bitItemLites;
    }
}

class Item {
   int qty;
   int price;

   factory Item.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) {
      return Item(json['qty'], json['price']);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to do something like this:

```dart
//...
Future<List<ItemModel>> fetchFood() async {

    List<ItemModel> foodItemsList = [];

    // Get json response and parse it as a Map<String, dynamic>
    final response = {
       "data" : {
            "apple":{"qty":5, "price":100},
            "orange":{"qty":2, "price":40},
           }
       };
    // with your real get request use this:
    // final parsedJson = json.decode(response.body)['data'];

    // Parsed Json have what's inside data, in case of real request look for the line above this.
    final parsedJson = response['data'];

    // Iterate over all fruits and create Item object from each,
    // then push to a list of Item's objects to return it.
    parsedJson.forEach((k,v) => foodItemsList.add(ItemModel.fromJson(v)));

    return foodItemsList;
}

// Item model
class ItemModel {
   int qty;
   int price;

   ItemModel.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> parsedJson)
      : qty = parsedJson['qty'],
        price = parsedJson['price'];

}

// Then call it
main() async {

  List<ItemModel> foodItemsList = await fetchFood();
  //..
}
```

**If you need the fruit name as part of the object**:

```dart
//...
Future<List<ItemModel>> fetchFood() async {

    List<ItemModel> foodItemsList = [];

    // Get json response and parse it as a Map<String, dynamic>
    final response = {
       "data" : {
            "apple":{"qty":5, "price":100},
            "orange":{"qty":2, "price":40},
           }
       };
    // with your real get request use this:
    // final parsedJson = json.decode(response.body)['data'];

    // Parsed Json have what's inside data, in case of real request look for the line above this.
    final parsedJson = response['data'];

    // Iterate over all fruits and create Item object from each,
    // then push to a list of Item's objects to return it.
    parsedJson.forEach((fruitName, fruitDetails) 
        => foodItemsList.add(
             ItemModel.fromJson(fruitName, fruitDetails)
        )
    );

    return foodItemsList;
}

// Item model
class ItemModel {
   String name;
   int qty;
   int price;

   ItemModel.fromJson(String fruitName, Map<String,dynamic> parsedJson)
      : name = fruitName,
        qty = parsedJson['qty'],
        price = parsedJson['price'];

}

// Then call it
main() async {

  List<ItemModel> foodItemsList = await fetchFood();
  print(foodItemsList[1].name); //orange
  //..
}
```

Comment: Here the keys are dynamic, you dont know the name of the fruit!

Comment: @YudhishthirSingh Yes, I got the name by looping over the `response['data']`, then the fruitName will be the key of each item of `response['data'].forEach((fruitName, fruitDetails) => ...);`  similar to `response['data'].forEach((key, value)=> ...); `

Comment: How can I make the method wait to add data to the list. In my code, the return gets executed before I add data to the list. How can I make it wait for the forEach() to execute?

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar JSON with a few changes:

```
{
  "sub_item": {
    "491": ["92837|1.3|Pistachio|right", "92838|2.5|Hazelnut|left"],
    "427": ["92839|7.05|Almonds|", "92840|5.12|Walnuts|"],
    "396": ["92841|15|Saffron|"],
    "275": ["92842|45|Caviar|"]
  }
}
```

The keys of `sub_item` map (**491**, **427**, **396**, **275**, and...) are dynamic(as a label not as a type) and will change per order. For example, it will be 376, 325, 493... in another order.

I want to shows both keys and values on my Flutter app and do not know how to fetch these data and show them separately. Something like this:

```
491:
£1.30  Pistachio
£2.50  Hazelnut

427:
£7.05  Almonds
£5.12  Walnuts

396:
£15.00 Saffron

275:
£45.00 Caviar
```

I used this code and it worked for me somehow but it shows only the first item of the lists. for example, it shows only **Pistachio** for 491 not **Hazelnut** and the same it shows only **Almonds** for 427 not **Walnuts**:

```
Future<List<ItemModel>> fetchFood() async {
  List<ItemModel> foodItemsList = [];

  final response = {
    "sub_item": {
      "491": ["92837|1.3|Pistachio|right", "92838|2.5|Hazelnut|left"],
      "427": ["92839|7.05|Almonds|", "92840|5.12|Walnuts|"],
      "396": ["92841|15|Saffron|"],
      "275": ["92842|45|Caviar|"]
    }
  };

  final parsedJson = response['sub_item'];

  parsedJson.forEach((fruitName, fruitDetails) =>
      foodItemsList.add(ItemModel.fromJson(fruitName, fruitDetails)));

  return foodItemsList;
}

// Item model
class ItemModel {
  String id;
  String details;

  ItemModel.fromJson(String subItemID, List<dynamic> subItemDetails)
      : id = subItemID,
        details = subItemDetails[0];
}

// Then call it
mainTest() async {
  List<ItemModel> foodItemsList = await fetchFood();
  for (var i = 0, j = 0;
      i < foodItemsList.length;
      j < foodItemsList[i].details.length, i++, j++) {
    print(foodItemsList[i].id);
    print(foodItemsList[j].details.split('|')[2]);
  }
}
```

The console result:

```
flutter: 491
flutter: Pistachio
flutter: 427
flutter: Almonds
flutter: 396
flutter: Saffron
flutter: 275
flutter: Caviar
```